# Can't SSH into my server from my Mac Terminal and rsync over SSH is suddenly broken too

Tags: ssh, debian, rsync, login, mac

all of a sudden I can't login to my server from my Mac Terminal. On my Linux machine normal ssh login still works, except rsync over ssh also gets stuck.

This is what happenes when I try to connect from my Mac:

```
ssh -v user@xx.xx.xx.xx
OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx [xx.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/xx/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xx/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xx/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xx/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xx/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xx/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xx/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xx/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xx/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to xx.xx.xx.xx:22 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: 
debug1: Host 'xx.xx.xx.xx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/xx/.ssh/known_hosts:28
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xx/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xx/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xx/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xx/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xx/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@xx.xx.xx.xx's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to xx.xx.xx.xx ([xx.xx.xx.xx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
packet_write_wait: Connection to xx.xx.xx.xx port 22: Broken pipe
```

It was all working fine, and then suddenly it stopped working. I didn't change anything on the server config. Just did some backups via rsync and then in the middle of it rsync just stopped working. It seems to hang at the same place:

```
Authenticated to xx.xx.xx.xx ([xx.xx.xx.xx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: rsync --server --sender -vltpre.iLsfxC . folder
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to check the server to find out what has happened.

Comment: how do I do that?
Looking in the sshd logs at /var/log/auth.log I only find like
sshd[16224]: Accepted password for user from my.local.ip.addr port 40985 ssh2

Comment: You could start by logging in to the server and checking its logs.

Comment: looks like it's able to log in but somehow it doesn't start a shell session